# I am using the check box as image chk.jpg it is working fine in Google Chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I am using the check box for an image; it is working fine in Chrome but not in the Firefox so i try so many times to solve this problem but not yet i find it.

This check box i am using in the mailpoet newsletter plugin and connected with my style.css

Html code

```
<p class="wysija-checkbox-paragraph"><label><input class="wysija-checkbox validate[required]" name="wysija[user_list][list_id][]" type="checkbox" value="3" checked="checked" /> Monthly Printed</label>

</p>

<p>  <label class="wysija-checkbox-label"><input class="wysija-checkbox " type="checkbox" name="wysija[field][cf_2]" value="1" />Anboli Daily Email Edition</label></p>
```

style.css

```css
.checkbox   /*before checked the check box*/
{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: -10px 5px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url (http://example.com/uploads/2014/04/chk.jpg) left -35px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkbox:checked /*after checked*/
{
    background: url(http://example.com/uploads/2014/04/chk.jpg) left 0px no-repeat;
}
```

help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a generic sample below, using almost the same structure as you. What I did was I put the label after the checkbox, and hid the check box by giving it a width and height of 0. Then I used the css '+' selector to select the label directly after a checked checkbox and change the background of that label. Of course, the label will now act as a checkbox because clicking on a label still checks the hidden checkbox!

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="check1"/>
<label for="check1"></label>
```

CSS:

```
/*before check*/
label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -10px 5px 0 0;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background: url (http://example.com/uploads/2014/04/chk.jpg) left -35px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*after check*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background: url(http://example.com/uploads/2014/04/chk.jpg) left 0px no-repeat;
}

/*hide the checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
  height: 0em;
  width: 0em;
  background: none;
}
```